# Putting the same data from a variable on its own line?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, asterisk

I have a script that I'm going to use for our FreePBX with Asterisk phone system. I would like to know if any of our extensions/endpoints are offline/unavailable, I would like to be sent that info in an email.

```
#!/bin/bash

email="my-email@my-domain.com"

offlineExtensions=$(asterisk -rx 'pjsip show contacts' | grep -i "unavail")

if [ "$offlineExtensions" ]
then
echo $offlineExtensions | mail -s "Extensions Offline" $email
fi
```

My email looks like...

```
Contact: 7101/sip:7101@IP_ADDRESS:5060 d20a378e88 Unavail 55.829 Contact: 7770/sip:7770@IP_ADDRESS:5060 174a796f10 Unavail 12.275
```

I would like the contacts info to be on their own separate line, not concatenated together. I've used the next line symbol(\n) in the script but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 2):

Your contacts get concatenated because you didn't quote `$offlineExtensions` in `echo $offlineExtensions | ...`.  The variable has the newlines intact, but then the shell splits it into words, then joins the words separated by spaces.  To prevent that you need to enclose `$offlineExtensions` in double quotes.  For the same reason it's good hygiene to also quote `$email` (although leaving it unquoted is harmless in this particular situation).

An unrelated problem lurking in your script is that you're using `echo` to print a variable with unknown contents.  If `$offlineExtensions` happens to start with a dash `-`, `echo` will take that as an option.  Some implementations of `echo` allow you to avoid that problem by using `echo --` instead of just `echo`, others don't.  The portable way to deal with it is to use `printf` instead of `echo`.

Summarizing, replace the `echo ...` line by:

```
printf '%s\n' "$offlineExtensions" | mail -s 'Extensions Offline' "$email"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try use

```
pjsip show contact concise
```

But that is not best option anyway.

Best practice is parse /var/log/asterisk/messages or full file(it can be setuped to put record when someone go unreachable/reachable).

Best practice is use nagios or other monitoring soft, not write your own.

Answer (score -1):

My final script that works. Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash

email="my-email@my-domain.com"

offlineExtensions=$(asterisk -rx 'pjsip show contacts' | grep -i "unavail")

if [ "$offlineExtensions" ]
then
printf "$offlineExtensions" | mail -s 'Extensions Offline' "$email"
fi
```

Comment: No, that's definitely _not_ how to use `printf`!  If the variable contains a `%` character, this will be interpreted as a formatting string.  See Satō Katsura's answer again. And accept that answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: I've tested this script and it works the way I want it too. Could you tell me please what you think is wrong with it? Thank you.

Comment: I believe I did. printf should always be used with a formatting string, as in Sato's answer.